# Valgrind doesn't see lines in -g file

Tags: c, debugging, ubuntu-16.04, valgrind

My valgrind for some reason doesn't happen to print the line number and the file the error happens at. This happens in a Linux Ubuntu 16.04.4 distro.

Here is how I have tested it:

/tmp/a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *buf = malloc(10);

    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

I executed it all with the following command: `cd /tmp && gcc a.c -o hello -fno-stack-protector -fno-builtin -g && valgrind ./hello`

```
$ cd /tmp && gcc a.c -o hello -fno-stack-protector -fno-builtin -g && valgrind ./hello ./hello
==23422== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23422== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23422== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23422== Command: ./hello
==23422== 
==23422== Invalid read of size 1
==23422==    at 0x4C31047: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23422==    by 0x40119C: ??? (in /tmp/hello)
==23422==    by 0x4E5A82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==23422==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==23422== 
==23422== 
==23422== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==23422==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==23422==    at 0x4C31047: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23422==    by 0x40119C: ??? (in /tmp/hello)
==23422==    by 0x4E5A82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==23422==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==23422==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==23422==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==23422==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==23422==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==23422== 
==23422== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23422==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==23422==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 10 bytes allocated
==23422== 
==23422== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23422==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23422==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23422==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23422==    still reachable: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==23422==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23422== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==23422== 
==23422== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23422== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

GCC Version: `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)`
Valgrind Version: `valgrind-3.11.0`

I also tried downloading and compiling the latest valgrind version (`valgrind-3.13.0`) but ended with the same issue.

EDIT:

Output with full logs:

```
$ valgrind -v --leak-check=full /tmp/a.out
==17717== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17717== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17717== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17717== Command: /tmp/a.out
==17717== 
--17717-- Valgrind options:
--17717--    -v
--17717--    --leak-check=full
--17717-- Contents of /proc/version:
--17717--   Linux version 4.4.0-119-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-013) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) ) #143-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 16:08:24 UTC 2018
--17717-- 
--17717-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, LittleEndian, amd64-cx16-rdtscp-sse3-avx
--17717-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--17717-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--17717-- Reading syms from /tmp/a.out
--17717-- ELF section outside all mapped regions
--17717-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
--17717--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so ..
--17717--   .. CRC mismatch (computed aa979a42 wanted 9019bbb7)
--17717--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so ..
--17717--   .. CRC is valid
--17717-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--17717--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux ..
--17717--   .. CRC mismatch (computed eea41ea9 wanted 2009db78)
--17717--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--17717--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--17717-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--17717-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
==17717== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-17717-by-rajiska-on-???
==17717== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-17717-by-rajiska-on-???
==17717== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-17717-by-rajiska-on-???
==17717== 
==17717== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==17717== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==17717== or are doing some strange experiment):
==17717==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=17717 ...command...
==17717== 
==17717== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==17717==   /path/to/gdb /tmp/a.out
==17717== and then give GDB the following command
==17717==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=17717
==17717== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==17717== 
--17717-- REDIR: 0x401cfd0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x3809e181 (???)
--17717-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--17717--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so ..
--17717--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 2567ccf6 wanted 49420590)
--17717--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--17717-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--17717--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so ..
--17717--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 0e27c9a8 wanted ac585421)
--17717--    object doesn't have a symbol table
==17717== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--17717--     old: 0x0401cfd0 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x3809e181 ???
--17717--     new: 0x0401cfd0 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c31020 strlen
--17717-- REDIR: 0x401b920 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x4c30bc0 (index)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x401bb40 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4c320d0 (strcmp)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x401dd30 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c35270 (mempcpy)
--17717-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
--17717--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so ..
--17717--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 7a8ee3e4 wanted a5190ac4)
--17717--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so ..
--17717--   .. CRC is valid
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ec9a00 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ec5280 (libc.so.6:strcspn) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ecbcf0 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ec76f0 (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ec7a80 (libc.so.6:strspn) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ec914b (libc.so.6:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ec7400 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x4c308a0 (rindex)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ebe130 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x4c2db20 (malloc)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ec5160 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4edf9d0 (libc.so.6:__strcpy_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c31040 (strcpy)
==17717== Invalid read of size 1
==17717==    at 0x4C31047: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17717==    by 0x40119C: ??? (in /tmp/a.out)
==17717==    by 0x4E5A82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==17717==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==17717== 
==17717== 
==17717== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==17717==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==17717==    at 0x4C31047: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17717==    by 0x40119C: ??? (in /tmp/a.out)
==17717==    by 0x4E5A82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==17717==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==17717==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==17717==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==17717==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==17717==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
--17717-- REDIR: 0x4ebe4f0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2ed80 (free)
==17717== 
==17717== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17717==     in use at exit: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==17717==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 10 bytes allocated
==17717== 
==17717== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==17717== Checked 62,704 bytes
==17717== 
==17717== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17717==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17717==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17717==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17717==    still reachable: 10 bytes in 1 blocks
==17717==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17717== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==17717== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==17717== 
==17717== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==17717== 
==17717== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==17717== Invalid read of size 1
==17717==    at 0x4C31047: strcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17717==    by 0x40119C: ??? (in /tmp/a.out)
==17717==    by 0x4E5A82F: (below main) (libc-start.c:291)
==17717==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==17717== 
==17717== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDIT 2: After testing a binary compiled on my system under a Docker system, it appears the issue is the same which leads to think the problem is on the binary itself. Compiling with the GCC of the Docker system works fine with valgrind.

EDIT 3: Just compiled the latest GCC version (8.1.0) and tried compiling the program with it: same issue. Furthermore you may want to note that valgrind can't resolve the function the issue happens in, even though the executable is not striped.

Also, in the `valgrind -v` command, we can see the note `ELF section outside all mapped regions` while reading the symbols of the executable.

I'm kinda lost there, it looks like it doesn't come from either GCC or Valgrind. Maybe some kind of system configuration ?

Comment: Are you really running the program you think you're running? Is your current directory `/tmp`? What if you just do e.g. `valgrind ./a.out` what happens then?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Valgrind confirms the path of the file. File not found when running with `./a.out`. I even tried setting the `-o` file of GCC to set the name to something else and calling valgrind over it, same issue.

Comment: If you do `gcc a.c -g` and followed by `valgrind ./a.out` and getting the error message that Valgrind can't find your program is highly suspect. Please edit your question to include the *exact* commands you use to build and run Valgrind, including the path you're doing this in.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's effectively suspect. Just edited the command with the full output. Some weeks ago I had the full Ubuntu desktop that went away and had to redownload all the Ubuntu base packages. Maybe valgrind / gcc requires some other packages which I did not redownload ?

Comment: Just added a few details, it doesn't seem to come from GCC nor Valgrind themselves. But something must be happening while it's compiling.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just for the record, solution found ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Fixed

After testing the compilation with a different user, valgrind was able to detect the lines and functions the issues were appearing at. It took me no long after to figure out the issue came from my `~/.profile` file where I edited my `$PATH` to give the precedence to a local architecture present in my `$HOME` directory. GCC must have been fetching some of its libraries from there which resulted in debug symbols not being fully generated.

Fixed it all by editing the `$PATH` variable back to the way it used to.

EDIT:

I finally found out the exact reason why it did not work. Basically as a temp fix I was simply setting in my `$PATH` my local-user bin folder where I compiled many system binaries for them to be up to date.

The binary `ld` (2.30.51.20180501) was causing the issue. Removing it from my `$PATH` allowed my valgrind to work as intended again.

Answer (score 0):

I use RedHat6 and valgrind 3.9.0.
I have tested the following compilers. With all compiler I used the debug flag `-g`

**clang 4.0**

```
==8862== Invalid read of size 1
==8862==    at 0x4A09097: strcpy (in /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8862==    by 0x400566: main (valg.c:10)
==8862==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

**intel icc 15.0.3**

```
==8250== Invalid read of size 1
==8250==    at 0x4A09097: strcpy (in /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8250==    by 0x4005D2: main (valg.c:10)
==8250==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

**gcc 4.8.2**

```
==8862== Invalid read of size 1
==8862==    at 0x4A09097: strcpy (in /opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8862==    by 0x400566: main (valg.c:10)
==8862==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

All of them show the correct `Invalid read of size 1`.
A proper `signal 11` is thrown, when executing the program.

It is not important, if you use `-v` or `--leak-check=full`.

I know that this is not an answer, but it was too long for a comment.

Comment: I've tried out with clang, it seems to work correctly. However when I work with GCC, Valgrind reports a "ELF section outside all mapped regions" error.